# evt || window.evt causing JS error in chrome & IE

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a function which should be called on loading and clicking a button. For example this is function

```
function addChild(evt){
   //Some functionality goes here
   if(evt || window.evt) dojo.stopEvent(evt);
}
```

And now I am calling the addChild on both loading and clicking an button as

```
 if(noChilds > 3){ 
    addChild();
 }
 dojo.connect(btn, 'onclick', addChild);
```

The line if(evt || window.evt) dojo.stopEvent(evt); is causing error in chrome & IE on loading of page because the evt is going as undefined. But in firefox it is working fine though evt is passed as undefined.

Once I conditionalized the line if(evt || window.evt) as

```
if(evt){
   if(evt || window.evt) dojo.stopEvent(evt);
}
```

it is working fine on all browsers.

Is there any reason for chrome & IE behaves like this?

Comment: if `evt` is null but `window.evt` is not null then it will try to do `dojo.stopEvent` so I would assume that window.evt is different on chrome and firefox. Have you checked what the value of window.evt is in the different cases?

Comment: Yes window.evt is causing the problem. Actually I am writing this whole functionality in Ajax request.so, window.evt is assigned with XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent on clicking the button.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, on loading the page is rendering fine. But on clicking button only the Js error is happening in Chrome & IE but not in firefox.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you said there but I've just noticed something else. You say "in firefox it is working fine though evt is passed as undefined" - if evt is undefined what exactly are you expecting dojo.stopEvent(evt) to do? You seem to imply its doing the right thing but I can't see how it would do anything (though I don't know what this dojo is). You might want to look into the documentation for whatever dojo is and find out whether null should be acceptable or not. It certainly seems strange to say "If window.evt is truthy then I'm fine with passing null to this method.